# Sharepoint Online workflow for all selected documents

Tags: rest, sharepoint, power-automate

Is it possible to create a workflow with MS SharePoint and MS Flow that on a button click for all selected items in document library asks for several information to be entered and when confirm button is pressed it will executed a REST API call?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Nintex workflow - and it seems that it is doable in MS flow as well. Please have a look at the below thread where similar functionality is implemented using MS Flow:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Run-Flow-on-Multiple-List-Items-in-SharePoint-Online-List/td-p/147753